# One-to-one DataMapper association

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I'm very new to DataMapper, and I'm trying to create models for the following scenario:

I've got a number of users (with a user name, password etc.), who can also be players or referees or both (so Single Table Inheritance is not an option). The base models would be:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  # Other user properties go here  
end

class Player
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  # Other player properties go here
  # Some kind of association goes here
end

class Referee
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  # Other referee properties go here
  # Some kind of association goes here
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

I'm not sure, though, what kinds of associations to add to Player and Referee. With `belongs_to :user`, multiple players can be associated with the same user, which doesn't make sense in my context. In RDBMS terms I guess what I want is a unique constraint on the foreign key in the Players and Referees tables.

How do I accomplish this in my DataMapper model? Do I have to perform the check myself in a validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways you could do this. Here's one option:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  # Other properties...
  has 1, :referee, :required => false
  has 1, :player, :required => false
end

class Referee
  include DataMapper::Resource
  # DON'T include "property :id, Serial" here
  # Other properties...
  belongs_to :user, :key => true
end
class Player
  include DataMapper::Resource
  # DON'T include "property :id, Serial" here
  # Other properties...
  belongs_to :user, :key => true
end
```

Act on the referee/player models like:

```
u = User.create(...)
u.referee = Referee.create(...)
u.player = Player.create(...)

u.player.kick_ball() # or whatever you want to call
u.player.homeruns
u.referee.flag_play() # or whatever.
```

See if this works. I haven't actually tested it but it should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These models still allow me to create multiple players that are associated with the same user, though.

Comment: @mwittrock I see. Edited to prevent that. Now the "subclasses" use the User foreign key as their primary keys.

Comment: This does seem to be the correct one-to-at-most-one association in DataMapper. Enjoy a helping of reputation :-)

Comment: Oh, bounty can be awarded in 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer works other than `:required => false` is not recognized for `has 1` properties.

It's also confusing because for `has n` properties, you can use `new` right on the property or otherwise treat it as a collection. In your example, you would be tempted to code

```
u = User.create ...
u.referee.create ...
```

But that fails in the case of `has 1` because the property is a single value, which begins life as `nil` and so you have to use the method the previous answer indicates. Also, having to explicitly make the `belongs_to` association into the key is a little confusing.

It does seem to execute validations and have the right association actions (so u.save will also save the referred-to `Referee`). I just wish it were more consistent between `has n` and `has 1`.