# Trouble linking one-to-one models in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, associations, datamapper, one-to-one

Using `PostgreSQL` and `DataMapper` to build a Sinatra app, running into some problems with `DataMapper` (I'm very new to it, used to `Rails/AR`). For every `Account` created, it can either be an `Artist`, `Venue`, or `Fan`. Only one, no combining.

When the user signs up, I can create the `Account` instance fine, but I'm having trouble creating the account's has 1 `Artist` or `Venue` or `Fan` instance (for ease of conversation, we'll use `Artist` as the belonging model).

Here's my current model declarations:

```
class Account
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,           Serial
    ...

    has 1, :artist, :required => false
    has 1, :venue, :required => false
    has 1, :fan, :required => false
end

class Artist
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # no ID
    ...

    belongs_to :account, :key => true
end

class Venue
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # no ID
    ...

    belongs_to :account, :key => true
end

class Fan
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # no ID
    ...

    belongs_to :account, :key => true
end
```

And here's how I'm trying to go about the sign up process:

```
account = Account.create(
    ...
)

account.Artist = Artist.create(:bio => "test")
```

This is currently giving me next error:

```
undefined method `Artist=' for #<Account:0x007ff2af289840>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use lowercase letter in referring model:

```
account.artist = Artist.create(:bio => "test")
```

This line:

```
has 1, :artist, :required => false
```

Add a relation, by which you can refer from `Account` to `Artist`.

**Updated**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094964/724036) has exactly your model and seems like it worked. There is `DataMapper.finalize` thing, i guess you made it.

Comment: that gives me this error: undefined local variable or method `artist' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007ff2b0022498>

Comment: What if you remove `, :required => false`

Comment: Or it is something like embedded in mongodb?

Comment: i'm using postgresql - removing the required line didn't change the error :(

Comment: Yes, i checked that it's another thing, and you need it in your case.

Comment: I guess you should update question to this new error, cause you should definitely use `account.artist` to refer to relation.

Comment: just figured it out. i followed the setup given by the link, but it still didn't work. the parent record was being created, but the belonged record was not. then i stumbled upon dm-noisy-failures gem, which reports errors that datamapper hides by default. quickly figured out that the solution was to include a :account_id => account.id attribute when creating the belonged (artist) record.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of frustration, I figured this out. i hope my answer helps anyone else out, as I couldn't find anything on the internet that outlined this (maybe I'm just bad at searching).

Per @zishe's updated answer, I followed the structure [he linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050891/one-to-one-datamapper-association/17094964#17094964), like thus:

```
class Account
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,           Serial
    ...

    has 1, :artist
    has 1, :venue
    has 1, :fan
end

class Artist
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # no ID
    ...

    belongs_to :account, :key => true
end
```

And for creating associated records:

```
a = Account.create(...)
a.artist = Artist.create(...)
```

Creating the parent record, the Account, worked fine, but the belonged record, Artist, was not created nor was an error reported. After some frustration, I stumbled upon dm-noisy-failures, which I 'gem installed' and required in my app. Note to other data_mapper noobs, that gem is a must have, and I personally think it's an extremely awry decision on datamapper's part to hide errors the way it does. Thanks to dm-noisy-failures, my error was made clear to me. The solution was to manually tell data_mapper the ID of the parent record when creating the Artist record, like thus:

```
a = Account.create(...)
a.artist = Artist.create(:account_id => a.id)
```

Worked like a charm. Thank you @zishe (point given) and contributors of the linked answer.

UPDATE: so now i really feel like an idiot. tucked away in [DataMapper's Associations documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html) under the subheader Adding To Associations (contrary to my comment below) is an example that explains exactly how to do 1-to-1 relationships. i completely overlooked this. sorry everyone, ashamed.

Comment: and yeah, i feel stupid because that should have been an obvious solution. i guess i was just assuming Data_Mapper took care of linking associations itself, didn't know I had to manually tell it to do that via properties. I'd also like to note that Data_Mapper does not have a 1-to-1 example in its immediately available documentation. That entire ordeal was confusing af, especially for someone going into it blind like me.